# Passing variables between routes in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, ajax, post, sinatra

I'm implementing sms-validation of registration on Sinatra site, and I got this code:

```
post '/reg' do
  phone = params[:phone].to_s
  code = Random.rand(1000..9999).to_s
  HTTParty.get('http://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=' + api_id + phone + '&text=' + code)
end
```

This take users phone from **post** request, than generates 4 digit code, and sends code on number via **get** request to sms service. But, page doesn't reloading, because at that moment opens modal dialog, where user should type *code*. Button which opens modal simultaneously sends **post** via Ajax with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sendsms").click(function(){
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/coop",
      data: {"phone": phone},
      type: "post"
    });
  });
});
```

It would be strange to check user's code on client side, thats why I got this action route:

```
post '/coop/checkcode' do
  usrcode = params[:code]
  if code == usrcode
    redirect '/reg/success'
  else
    redirect '/reg/fail'
  end
end
```

But I can't just take and type *code* var from first route in the *checkcode* route. But I need.

Is there exists any possible way to pass that variable or implement this somehow other way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using sessions: [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions)

first in config:

```
enable :sessions
```

now you get:

```
post '/reg' do
  phone = params[:phone].to_s
  session[:code] = Random.rand(1000..9999).to_s
  HTTParty.get('http://sms.ru/sms/send?api_id=' + api_id + phone + '&text=' + session[:code])
end
```

and

```
post '/coop/checkcode' do
  usrcode = params[:code]
  if session[:code] == usrcode
    redirect '/reg/success'
  else
    redirect '/reg/fail'
  end
end
```