# Run Ruby file from html form submit

Tags: ruby, html, forms, sinatra

I have a Ruby program that reads a file and returns a certain output. I have to now create a web app of this program using Sinatra. I created a `form` with all the file options and I want to now run that Ruby code with that selected file from the form after the submit button is pressed.

Basically, I’m not sure how to get this external Ruby program to run with the the filename that was selected by the user from the HTML `form`.

The Ruby program (`example.rb`) starts with the definition `def read_grammar_defs(filename)`.

```
// sinatra_main.rb

require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development? #gem install sinatra-contrib
require './rsg.rb'

get '/' do
 erb :home
end

post '/p' do
  //call program to read file with the parameter from form 
end




// layout.erb

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title><%= @title || "RSG" %></title>
  <meta charset="UTF8">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>RubyRSG Demo</h1>
 <p>Select grammar file to create randomly generated sentence</p>
 <form action="/p" method="post">
  <select name="grammar_file">
      <option value="Select" hidden>Select</option>
      <option value="Poem">Poem</option>
      <option value="Insult">Insult</option>
      <option value="Extension-request">Extension-request</option>
      <option value="Bond-movie">Bond-movie</option>
 </select>
 <br><br>
 </form>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
<section>
 <%= yield %>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is as follows:

1. Package the `example.rb` code into a class or module like so:

   ```
   class FileReader
     def self.read_grammar_defs(filename)
       # ...
     end
   end
   ```
2. require the file from your sinatra server
3. Inside the `post` action, read the params and call the method:

   ```
   post '/p' do
     @result = FileReader.read_grammar_defs(params[:grammar_file])
     erb :home
   end
   ```

With this code, after submitting the form, it would populate the `@result` variable and render the `:home` template. Instance variables are accessible from ERB and so you could access it from therer if you wanted to display the result.

This is one potential issue with this, though - when the page is rendered the url will still say `"your_host.com/p"` and if the user reloads the page, they will get a 404 / "route not found" error because there is no `get "/p"` defined.

As a workaround, you can `redirect '/'` and use `session` as described [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621511/passing-variables-between-routes-in-sinatra) or [Sinatra' official FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions) to pass the result value.

Comment: i have <%=rsg(params[:grammar_file])%> inside home.erb but its printing to the console and not the page

Comment: putting it in the post method like rsg(params[:grammar_file]) also prints in the console...not sure why

Comment: anything? ive been stuck for hours

Comment: Uh .. what does the `rsg` method actually do? Does it return a string or just print it? (hint: `puts` returns nil)

Comment: it reads a file and generates a random sentence from the grammars in the file

Comment: I want to print the output on the web page which would be the random sentence butttttt it only prints it to the console

Comment: Why don't you just include the method in the question?

Comment: I fixed the problem!