# How to print to web page using Ruby and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm calling a ruby function in a post method and I'm trying to output the contents from the function to the web page but it prints the output in my console instead. How do I get it to print to the page?

I've tried

<%=rsg(params[:grammar_file])%> inside an erb file

and

rsg(params[:grammar_file])

inside of the post method and both just print to the console

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development? #gem install sinatra-contrib
require './rsg.rb'
enable :sessions

get '/' do
 erb :index

end

post '/' do
rsg(params[:grammar_file])
erb :index

end




<% title = "RANDOM SENTENCE GENERATOR" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title><%= @title || "RSG" %></title>
 <meta charset="UTF8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>RubyRSG Demo</h1>
<p>Select grammar file to create randomly generated sentence</p>
<form action="/" method="post">
   <select name="grammar_file">
     <option value="Select" hidden>Select</option>
     <option value="Poem">Poem</option>
     <option value="Insult">Insult</option>
     <option value="Extension-request">Extension-request</option>
     <option value="Bond-movie">Bond-movie</option>
   </select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<section>
  <p>Here</p>
  <p><%= rsg(params[:grammar_file])%></p>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you calling this endpoint in your webpage(javascript/jquery) ?

Comment: no jquery or javascript, just ruby

Comment: I thought doing <%=%> would print the contents to the web page but it just prints to the the the rubymine console

Comment: I tried it there too and it doesnt work, still prints to the console

Comment: can you post the entire code snippet so that we can try reproduce it ?

Comment: the first have is an main.rb file, second is layout.erb

Comment: the only time it actually prints to the web page is when i do <%= rsg(params[:grammar_file]).class%> in the html and it prints NilClass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Ruby file from html form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240589/run-ruby-file-from-html-form-submit)

Comment: well i took out the one in the html because it randomly stopped working...the other one in the post method still just post to the console not the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your template what to do with the params.

This is what is happening:

```
post '/' do
  rsg(params[:grammar_file])
  # your rsg method produces some output. I guess you have a line the `puts` your params to stdout somewhere. Instead you should redirect the output into the template.
  erb :index
end
```

Like this:

```
post '/' do
  erb :index, :locals => {:rsg => rsg(params[:grammar_file])}
end
```

Then, in your :index template you have a line like:

```
<%=rsg%>
```

To output the generated String.

The problem might also be that you're tryng to return a `puts` statement instead of the plain string:

```
def rsg(p)
  puts "I love my daily #{p}. Good luck to you"
end
```

This will just print to the console and nothing else (`true` to be precise)

Better:

```
def rsg(p)
  "I love my daily #{p}. Good luck to you"
end
```

Here you will just return the String from your method and calling `rsg("sandwich")` will return:

```
# => "I love my daily sandwich. Good luck to you"
```